# :appcompileDebugKotlin unresolved reference: showOrhide

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new at learning android studio but my college has given a project.
I have decided to tweak this(https://github.com/naman14/TimberX.git) project. (sorry but I am unable to find a guide to help me to build a music player)
So I changed the package name to com.example.shuffler and change applicationId same as changed package name. also I changed the JSON file which is giving me some different error.
but after changing the JSON file I get an error [errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlnLq.png)
**:appcompileDebugKotlin
unresolved reference: showOrhide** with 20 warnings.

please help me.

or

can you give me a detailed guide to building a full-fledged music player on the android studio (if the above request is unethical then sorry I am new at community)

Answer (score 0):

`showOrHide` is an extension function located in `com.naman14.timberx.extensions.ViewExtensions.kt`

Since you changed all the packages, make sure you also updated the imports in all classes

Comment: I don't understand what you say I'm such a noob. can you explain to me how to update all classes